# Доказать родство словосочетаний

Tags: недопустимая-метка, словосочетания

Пишу работу по социологии. По ряду параметров работа синергетическая. В части лингвистики прочитала массу материала. Ответа не нашла. Суть вопроса: в какой связи (с точки зр.лингвистики, м.б. науки логики) находятся между собой словосочетания: Основное рассматриваемое словосочетание:  ПРАВО НА ИНФОРМАЦИЮ Словосочетания – «оппоненты»:  Общественный договор Совместные декларации Право дать согласие Регулирование прав и свобод Собственное согласие Трактовка взаимоотношений Согласие, данное через народных представителей Представительство народа в законодательном собрании Право организовывать мирные сходки Собрание для обсуждения трактат Письменное или устное обращение Право добиваться и обретать счастье Общие интересы Избирательное право Создание и формирование законов, актов, ортодоксов выборы Написание статей, издание сборников Договор Коллективное управление Идея равенства свободы Избирательные права Совещательный орган Совет колонии ассамблея самоуправление и др. 
Цель: Как научно «узаконить» смысловое родство этих словосочетаний? Спасибо.

Comment: Татьяна, вам уже был дан ответ на этот вопрос. Почему вы опять задаете этот вопрос? Если вас не удовлетворил ответ, советую обратиться на Грамму.ру или на Грамоту.ру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ключевые словосочетания по теме "Право на информацию".